# What is the use of distro less yocto image and how to set it in local.conf file

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am browsing the meta-raspberry layer and in the Readme file they mention

```
The core BSP part of meta-raspberrypi should work with different
OpenEmbedded/Yocto distributions and layer stacks, such as:

* Distro-less (only with OE-Core).
* Angstrom.
* Yocto/Poky (main focus of testing).
```

How can i generate a distro-less image for Raspberry Pi3 and what is the difference between having a distro : DISTRO="poky"

Answer (score 0):

1) From meta-poky/README.poky

OpenEmbedded-Core is a layer containing the core metadata for current versions
of OpenEmbedded. It is distro-less (can build a functional image with
DISTRO = "nodistro") and contains only emulated machine support. [1]

[1] https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta-poky/README.poky#n23

This should explain how you generate a distro-less image

2) A distro defines policies like build configuration policy.

Here[2] you can see 4 different distros. poky-xxx

[2] https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta-poky/conf/distro

3) Having said that I let it up to you to experiment with distro-less images for the Raspberry Pi3 ;)